# Divide dataframes of different size based on same key values

Tags: python, pandas

Context: I have 2 dataframes one with weekly sums for a given month/year, etc and another dataframe that takes the sum of that given month/ year. This is done to get the % values.

Lets say we have dataframe 1 with the total counts:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A'], 
              'Col2':['B1','B2','B3'],'Total_Counts':[10,20,30]})

  Col1 Col2  Total_Counts
0    A   B1            10
1    A   B2            20
2    A   B3            30
```

And dataframe 2 with the weekly counts:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'], 
              'Col2':['B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3'],
              'Weekly_Counts':[1,4,6,10,4,6,12,12,6]})

  Col1 Col2  Weekly_Counts
0    A   B1              1
1    A   B2              4
2    A   B3              6
3    A   B1             10
4    A   B2              4
5    A   B3              6
6    A   B1             12
7    A   B2             12
8    A   B3              6
```

How can I divide element by element matching col1 and col2?

I was trying this:

```
result= (weekly_dataframe.merge(total_dataframe,
                 left_on=['Col1','Col2'],
                right_on=['Col1','Col2'],how='left')
              .assign(new=lambda x:round(x['Weekly_Counts'].div(x['Total_Counts'])*100,2))
.reindex(columns=[*weekly_dataframe.columns]+['Percentage']))
```

But the new column `percentage` keeps giving `NaN`

Desired output:
So when I just do `weekly_dataframe.merge(total_dataframe,left_on=['Col1','Col2'], right_on=['Col1','Col2'],how='left')` I get to this image with `Total_Counts_x` and `Total_Counts_y`

[image: What I have]

When I change the code to this (note I added Total_Count_x and y):

```
result= (weekly_dataframe.merge(total_dataframe,
                 left_on=['Col1','Col2'],
                right_on=['Col1','Col2'],how='left')
              .assign(new=lambda x:round(x['Total_Counts_x'].div(x['Total_Counts_y'])*100,2))
.reindex(columns=[*weekly_dataframe.columns]+['Percentage']))
```

I get this:

[image: Result]

How could I fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: what the expected output should look like? can you write it a table?

Comment: Hey I added some more input

Comment: I'll test it out now, one second :)

Comment: I get the perrcentage, but they're in wrong results (total counts shows as 17 for a given month, but the actual total is over 200)

Comment: can you refer to the data as you have posted in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248420/discussion-between-naveed-and-roo).

Comment: your desired output is not relatable with your starting data. those should reconcile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the issue was actually on the name created on one of the initial groupbys.

```
    weekly= dataframe.groupby(['X','Y','Weeks']).size().reset_index(name='Total_Weekly')

    totals_by_X = weekly.groupby(['X','Y'])['Total_Weekly'].sum().reset_index() 
    totals_by_Y = totals_by_sentiment.groupby(['X'])['Total_Weekly'].sum()

    weekly= (totals_by_Y .merge(totals_by_X ,left_on=['X'],right_on=['X'],how='left').assign(new=lambda x:round(x['Total_Weekly_x'].div(x['Total_Weekly_y'])*100,2)))
```

A bit confusing for given the complexity of the dataset, but it worked out in the end

Thanks anyone for those that gave an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using [**`pandas.DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), you don't need to reindex the cols to rename the %.

Try this :

```
result= (
    weekly_dataframe.merge(total_dataframe,on=['Col1','Col2'],how='left')
                    .assign(Percentage=lambda x:round(x['Weekly_Counts'].div(x['Total_Counts'])*100,2))
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(result)

  Col1 Col2  Weekly_Counts  Total_Counts  Percentage
0    A   B1              1            10        10.0
1    A   B2              4            20        20.0
2    A   B3              6            30        20.0
3    A   B1             10            10       100.0
4    A   B2              4            20        20.0
5    A   B3              6            30        20.0
6    A   B1             12            10       120.0
7    A   B2             12            20        60.0
8    A   B3              6            30        20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, is that what you're looking for? map will have a better performance over the merge

```
# create a dictionary of the col2 and total-counts from DF
d=dict(df[['Col2', 'Total_Counts']].values)

# map the total count from df using dict
df2['Total_counts'] = df2['Col2'].map(d)

#calculate
df2['percentage']=(df2['Weekly_Counts']/df2['Total_counts'] )*100
df2
```

```
   Col1     Col2    Weekly_Counts   Total_counts    percentage
0     A     B1                  1             10    10.0
1     A     B2                  4             20    20.0
2     A     B3                  6             30    20.0
3     A     B1                  10            10    100.0
4     A     B2                  4             20    20.0
5     A     B3                  6             30    20.0
6     A     B1                  12            10    120.0
7     A     B2                  12            20    60.0
8     A     B3                  6             30    20.0
```